# Creating and use a static library with g++

Tags: static, g++

There was a week I'm learning and reading how to use my own static library in C++ and it's driving me crazy. I'm using Ubuntu and I have a class in /home/myFiles/lib I want to build my library:

```
//MyClass.h
//---------------------------------------------
#ifndef MYCLASS_H_
#define MYCLASS_H_

class MyClass {
public:
    int a;

    MyClass();
    virtual ~MyClass();
};

#endif
```

And

```
//MyClass.cpp
//------------------------------------------
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass() {
    a = 3;
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {
}
//------------------------------------------
```

And a test file in /home/myFiles/main where I want to use the library:

```
// test.cpp
//-------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "MyClass.h"

int main() {
    MyClass c = MyClass;

    cout << "Hello World!!!" << c.a << endl;
    return 0;
}
//----------------------------------------------
```

Using Ubuntu console I type:

In lib folder: `g++ -c MyClass.cpp`
`ar rsc libTesting.a MyClass.o`

In test folder: `g++ -c test.cpp -lTesting -L/home/myFiles/lib`

Then It returns: `test.cpp: error: MyClass.h: No such file or directory`

If I write: 
`g++ -o test.cpp -lTesting -L/home/myFiles/lib`

It deletes my file test.cpp

I know there is a lot of information about this but I don't understand why it don't recognize the `#include "MyClass.h"` and how can I use this using only the library without include the path with `-I/home/myFiles/lib`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you havn't indicate the include path, so gnu report the error.

try to add -I for your include path, or copy the .h file to your source directory.

Comment: But then, why create a library? what is the purpose of create a library? can I use functions of classes in a library without #include "MyClass.h"? cause, if I must use -I for include paths, there is no reason to create one isn't it?

Comment: If you create library, you can distribute the library to others (not source code), but you must distribute the library with .h files.